# Tabbased application showing view without tabviews showing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I want that my application launches first homeview with tabs: Information, Notification, Friends, options but home view is not part of any tab...
see image below….

homeview is having tabs but no tab is selected:

[image: homeview is having tabs but no tab is selected]

Comment: What do you mean by 'but home view is not part of any tab'?

Comment: You mean the view you've depicted (stay safe, I'm OK, unsure...) is visible, but no tab is selected?  Let's see your code; how do you layout your view hierarchy?

Comment: you may add tab bar in your first view in xib then you can set each tab of viewcontroller

Comment: in the image u can see that no tab is selected & still the viewcontroller containing 3 buttons(ok,unsure, help) is shown

Comment: @amrita still have a problem ??

Answer (score 1):

you can create an `UIView` and in `didLoad` add as  `sub-view` to your view and when any `tab` click remove it from `super-view` . or u can change the view for first tabe and remove it when press on any tab.

```
-(void)staySafe_meathod
{
  UIView *temp_one = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,120,120)];
  [self.view addsubView:temp_one];//or the tab view u set it default show when the app open.

}
```

then u call this meathon in didLoad